# Image source not readable. NotReadableException

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I have a Laravel api end point which is storing multiple images. Using the post method request, when I send request to the end point from front-end (vue) using axios, it is giving the above mentioned error.I am sending images[] array with base64 strings. **But the same end point works when I send post request from postman.**
Kindly help. Writen Below is my request

```
     axios.post("http://localhost:8000/api/contactMessage", formData, {
       headers: {
         "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
       }

    })
    .then(function() {
      console.log("SUCCESS!!");
    })
    .catch(function() {
      console.log("FAILURE!!");
    });
}
```

And here is the postman request screenshot [image]

Comment: Can you please share your code.

Comment: @Sehdev I have shared my request code.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple to handle, you have to remove pubic_path().
secondly don't use base64 image as a source. Encode the string before sending the request to postman collection api